# In draw.io, how to move a node in front of another one?

Tags: draw.io

I create a Horizontal Tree Layout and create some nodes in Draw.io.
[tree node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtK0G.png)
How to move "item 1" in front of "item 2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible at the moment but you can vote and track this request here: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/1680

Regards,